# Adjective to describe someone hiding knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't seem to recall an informal or idiomatic word that describes someone who doesn't like share what he knows, in the context of scientific knowledge. I thought it's "scringy" but that's not the right word. Any help?

Example: "Come on man, tell me how you fixed the zombie zapper, don't be ____."

Comment: Likly it’s ***stingy***

Comment: There are some options here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57509/what-do-you-call-someone-who-has-extensive-knowledge-but-wont-share-it

Comment: Yes, I believe it's stingy. Thanks also for the question link.

Answer (score 2):

*Stingy* is usually used to describe someone who is cheap with money, not knowledge. The word *unforthcoming* seems like it would be a much better fit for someone who withholds information.

Defined by Google's dictionary as:

1. (of a person) not willing to divulge information.
2. (of something required) not ready or made available when wanted or needed.